# Using a String to access an object's parameter (APEX)

Tags: apex, custom-object, map, list

I have a list that contains an object's parameters that I'd like to access from the object. Below is an example of what I am trying to do

```
//temp is the name of an object which contains all of the parameters in parameterList
String[] parameterList = new String[]{'field1', 'field5', 'field6'};
Map<String, Object> data = new Map<String, Object>();

for (int i = 0; i < parameterList.length(); i++){
    parameter_value = temp.parameterList.get(i);
    data.add(parameterList.get(i), parameter_value);
}
```

The problem of course is the first line within the for statement. The string `parameterList.get(i)` is a string of the parameter I am trying to access from the `temp` object. How can I access that object parameter from the string?

EDIT:
To try and clarify, suppose that earlier on in the code we have that `temp.field1 = 5`. What I'm trying to do in the for loop is access that value.

EDIT 2: Thanks to the answer below I was able to figure it out. Below is the new code snippet:

```
String[] parameterList = new String[]{'field1', 'field5', 'field6'};
Map<String, Object> data = new Map<String, Object>();

for (Integer i = 0; i < parameterList.length(); i++){
    data.put(parameterList.get(i), temp.get(parameterList.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't really make sense here, as `temp` is null and completely unrelated to `parameterList`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson you're right, temp is an object that is defined much earlier on in the code. I will make that more clear. What's important is that temp is an object and the strings in parameterList contain Strings of parameters of temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a field dynamically you should do something like this:

```
parameter_value = temp.get(parameterList.get(i));
```

which would look like

```
parameter_value = temp.get('field1');
```

This is assuming temp is an object which you queried previously.

You will likely have to cast these values to make them consistent for the map. Like:

```
String parameter_value = (String) temp.get(parameterList.get(i));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!